# Solving differential equation and plotting the solution looks impossible while changing the parameter slightly

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation and plot the function in mathematica. The equation is $\left(\dfrac{dr}{d\phi}\right)^{2}-\dfrac{r^{4}}{b^{2}}+r^{2}-2r=0$
with the boundary condition $r(\phi=0)=\infty$. My mathematica code is:

```
ClearAll[]; 
b = Sqrt[28]; 
eqn = r'[\[Phi]]^2 - r[\[Phi]]^4/ b^2 + (1 -2/r[\[Phi]]) r[\[Phi]]^2 == 0; 
bc = r[0] == 1000; 
sol = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, r[\[Phi]], {\[Phi], 0, 8 \[Pi]}]; 
P2 = PolarPlot[r[\[Phi]] /. sol[[1, 1]], {\[Phi], 0, 8 \[Pi]},PlotStyle -> {Red}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
Plot[r[\[Phi]] /. sol[[1, 1]], {\[Phi], 0, 4 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle ->{Red}, Frame -> True]
```

The equation is solved and plotted for $b=3\sqrt{3}$. But when I change the value of b, computation is not working. I want to plot the figure1 as given in the paper https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-93595-w